# why no source code info for system libraries in debug symbols from Debuginfod of 22.04

Tags: software-sources, debug

I'm debugging my app in a 22.04 system(with WSL2), using vscode and gdb. I've setup the debuginfod services according to the official docs already, everything goes well. the debug console output and the "info sharedlibrary" all indicate the symbols of the system libraries are loaded. But whenever I'd like to step into some functions provided by system libraries, for example, a gtk3 function, the call stack view of vscode indicate that "Unknown Source". What's wrong?